# AngularJS Filter Problems

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

SO my application gets a list of `Primary Resources`. These JSON objects contain an `ID`, the `Name`, and an array of `role` objects. Each `role` object has a `value` and `name`. When the user selects a the `Primary Resource` from a select tag, I need another select tag to populate with their `role` values, as some `Primary Resources` have multiple `roles`. It looks right to be, but clearly there is something wrong with it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NewTicketCtrl">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
              <label for="primaryResource"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Primary Resource</label>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="primary" ng-model="option.primary" ng-options="primary.id as primary.name for primary in primaryResources">
        </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
             <label for="role"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-lg"></i> Role</label>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="role" ng-model="option.role" ng-options="primary.role.value as primary.role.name for primary in primaryResources | filter:{primary:option.primary}">
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('NewTicketCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    //Gets data from a JSON file
    $http.get('res/formValues.json').success(function(data){

        $scope.formValues = data;

        //For simplicity purposes, I'm hard coding in the values 
        $scope.primaryResources = {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Smith, John",
        "role" : [
            {
                "value" : 1,
                "name" : "Technician"
            },
            {
                "value" : 5,
                "name" : "Administration"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Smith, Jane",
        "role" : [
            {
                "value" : 1,
                "name" : "Technician"
            },
            {
                "value" : 2,
                "name" : "Level 2 Technician"
            },
            {
                "value" : 3,
                "name" : "Level 3 Technician"
            }
        ]
    }

        //Used to store values for later use
        $scope.option = {
            status : $scope.formValues.status[0].value,
            priority : $scope.formValues.priority[0].value,
            ticketType : $scope.formValues.ticketType[0].value,
            workQueue : $scope.formValues.workQueue[0].value,
            primary : $scope.formValues.primaryResource[0].id,
            role : $scope.formValues.primaryResource[0].role[0].value
        };

    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question, but if I'm ignoring the formValues variable, here is a simplified [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GtVe7MqgvAhlNMH8i5Gr?p=preview) on how you can work with multiple select tags.

```
<div ng-controller="NewTicketCtrl">
 <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group">
            <label for="primaryResource"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Primary Resource</label>
      </div>
      {{selectedPrimaryResource}}
      <select class="form-control" id="primary" ng-model="selectedPrimaryResource" ng-options="primary as primary.name for primary in primaryResources">
      </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group">
           <label for="role"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-lg"></i> Role</label>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control" id="role" ng-model="selectedRole" ng-options="role as role.name for role in selectedPrimaryResource.role">
      </select>
      {{selectedRole}}
 </div>
</div>
```

In short, simply store the result of your first selection as an object and use that object for the second selection tag.

Comment: Perfect, that was just what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.primaryResourses` is an object but it looks like you want it to be an array.

For ng-options to work it should be an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.primaryResources = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Smith, John",
        "role": [
            { "value" : 1, "name" : "Technician" },
            { "value" : 5, "name" : "Administration" }]
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Smith, Jane",
        "role" : [
            { "value" : 1, "name" : "Technician" },
            { "value" : 2, "name" : "Level 2 Technician" },
            { "value" : 3, "name" : "Level 3 Technician" }]
    }];
```

Because role is an array you cant use 'role.value'. You would have to access it like this:

```
role[0].value or role[i].value   // with an index
```

But I don't think that's what you want - I think you want to populate a second array with corresponding roles.

That can be done like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
              <label for="primaryResource"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Primary Resource</label>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="primary" ng-model="option.primary" ng-change="setRoles(option.primary)" ng-options="primary.id as primary.name for primary in primaryResources">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
             <label for="role"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-lg"></i> Role</label>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="role" ng-model="option.role" ng-options="selected.value as selected.name for selected in RowOptions">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.setRoles = function(id) {
    $scope.RowOptions = $scope.primaryResources.filter(function(data) { 
        return data.id == id; })[0].role;
}
```